# C# 4.0 dynamic Office interop performance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamic, office-interop

I've taken an application that was developed in Visual Studio 2008 and used various Office libraries through COM Interop.  I began some proof of concept development using the dynamic keyword and Visual Studio 2010.  I found that performing the same tasks is around 5-10x slower using dynamic than the "old" way. Has anyone else experienced this level of performance degradation?  Is this known or should I find a way to report this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a known *performance* hit with the `dynamic` keyword. The reason for this is because it must box the values into the `object` type and then use the DLR (one-time) to compile it and evaluate it. This is going to take more time on the processor than if the type were known. You can see the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784317/c-sharp-dynamic-keyword-run-time-penalty) for a more expanded description.

Finally, in your case, it would be even worse because it's already a COM object so boxing and unboxing that object on top of the COM overhead is going to be exaggerated.