# How to convert object to correct type

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following code that resolve a service using the non generic method. I can not use the generic one that would have solved my issue because I don't know upfront the type that are going to be passed in.

I don't like the very last line, it works well but I was wondering if I can "Cast" my handler to the right interface in order to call directly the Handle method ? In my case I know for sure that the type returns by resolve is going to be of type handlerType .

```
var handlerType = typeof (IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof (TResponseData));
var handler = _container.Resolve(handlerType);
var resp = new Response<TResponseData>();
resp.Data =  (TResponseData) handler.GetType().GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler, new object[] {query});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the last using reflection, you can take advantage of `dynamic` keyword:

```
var handlerType = typeof (IQueryHandler<,>)
                       .MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof (TResponseData));
dynamic handler = _container.Resolve(handlerType);
var resp = new Response<TResponseData>();
resp.Data =  (TResponseData) handler.Handle(query);
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `dynamic` under the hood will be doing much the same thing as the Refection in the original code? ie that this is a difference in readability rather than efficiency?

Comment: @Chris: You can prefer [Eric's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478387/dynamic-and-performance) to understand more

Comment: @CuongLe: dynamic does allow me to save few keystrokes and I may use it as a last resort, but I was more interested in being able to cast to handlertype my handler ( autofac would not have been able to return anything not of this type anyway)

Comment: @Dave: Another approach is you can define a non-generic interface `IQueryHandler` and make generic interfaces IQueryHandler<,> inherits from non-generic interface.