# Optimising Method Calls on Dynamic Type

Tags: c#, performance, com, dynamic-language-runtime

I have the following code that instantiates a registered COM object

```
private dynamic server = null // Global variable.
...
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Svr.GrpCall");
this.server = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I can invoke methods from this COM/`dynamic` object just fine using very intuitive notation

```
string expectedResult = this.server.GroupInit(someString, someBoolean);
```

For single calls the performance of calling such methods through the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) is liveable. However, for one requirement I need to use a double `for` loop for thousands of records, which uses a method in the COM object that returns `void`

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXREC; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXFIELDS; j++)
        this.server.MakeRecord(s1, s2, str);
```

This is *MASSIVELY* slow. I am aware of this and Eric Lippert's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480977/626442 gives the exact cause of this performance bottle-neck.

To get around this I have attempted to define a global `Action` for the `MakeRecord` method that is under pressure

```
private Action<short, short, string> makeRecord;
```

where the plan is to use this in the for loop above. Before using this `Action`, I attempt to first initialise the server (as above) and then assign the `makeRecord` delegate to the COM method using

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Svr.GrpCall");
this.server = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("MakeRecord");
makeRecord = (Action<short, short, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, methodInfo);
```

But the `type.GetMethod("MakeRecord")` is returning `null`. So, my question is,

1. **If this *IS* the right methodology** to speed up my `dynamic` calls, how can I assign the COM method `MakeRecord` to my `Action` delegate?
2. **If this *IS NOT* the right methodology** to speed up my `dynamic` calls, what is?

Thanks for your time.

---

I have also tried doing

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo methodInfo = o.GetType().GetMethod("MakeRec");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know the slow behavior is due to the use of `dynamic`?

- Have you tried using strongly-typed managed wrappers for the COM interfaces and calling them directly (i.e. without using `dynamic` and without using any reflection methods)? You can add a reference to the COM assembly itself to create the managed wrapper automatically.
- Have you tried running your code *outside* the debugger? Running code in the debugger results in up to a 100:1 performance hit for method calls to native code, which includes COM interface calls.
- Have you considered updating the interface to provide a more direct implementation of the desired algorithm, such that you can make fewer function calls in managed code?

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I have profiled the code and can see that it is the `dynamic` calls to the COM object that are slow. It is recognized that these call can be very slow as the DLR has to work it magic on each call (described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478387/dynamic-and-performance)). With the 1st point do you mean creating a C# wrapper using 'Tlbimp.exe'? I have run the code in release mode & the results are the same. The COM library as it is third party and legacy. There is also no way to optimize my use of the calls as it is a shear weight of data situation...

Comment: In the profiler, how did you distinguish between the overhead of `dynamic` and the cost of the method itself? If `MakeRecord` is a slow method itself, then it doesn't matter whether or not you use `dynamic` because that's not the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. The reason I know that this method is 'non-slow' is that the legacy COM library comes with an old example VB6 application. This application can call the COM methods 'directly' and this can make calls to `MakeRecord` 6000 times in 5s. When I perform the exact same operation in C# using `dynamic` this time (for the exact same data set) increases to around 1min. Again, thanks for your time...

Comment: Sam, I have been away for a while before replying to your comment because I have been away looking at you profile -> ANTLR -> talk by Terence Parr -> buying book et al.! I am amazed at this work. I recently wrote a generic syntax highlighter (nothing compared to ANTLR) and have recently been asked to re-write an old C++ compiler/static analyzer for some pseudo-code used in the insurance industry, also adding different language formats...

Comment: Initially I 'gulped', thinking that this was going to be tough (but fun) - then I found ANTLR! Would it be okay to email you with a few brief questions on ANTLR before I launch in to my full attack?