# Generic printing of jagged arrays

Tags: c#, generics, jagged-arrays

I am currently working with lots of arrays and for debugging purposes I wrote a generic `Print()` method to print different kinds of arrays

```
static void Main()
{
    Print(new double[]{ 1, 2, 3 });

    // Output: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}

static void Print<T>(T[] array)
{
    int size = array.Length;
    if (size == 0)
        return;

    string str = "[ ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        str += array[i].ToString();

        if (i < size - 1)
            str += ", ";
    }

    str += " ]";

    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

which works fine so far. Then I wanted to print an array of arrays, like `double[][]`, and tried the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    Print(new double[][]
    {
        new double[] { 1, 2 },
        new double[] { 3, 4 },
        new double[] { 5, 6 },
    });

    // Output: [ 1, 2 ]
    //         [ 3, 4 ]
    //         [ 5, 6 ]
}

static void Print<T>(T[] array)
{
    if (array.Length == 0)
        return;

    if (array[0].GetType().IsArray)
    {
        foreach (var element in array)
        {
            Print<T>(element);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int size = array.Length;
        string str = "[ ";

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            str += array[i].ToString();

            if (i < size - 1)
                str += ", ";
        }

        str += " ]";

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

I just wanted to check if the elements of `array` again are arrays, and if so, I call the function Print again for each `element` of `array`. But `Print(element)` doesn't work, since `element` is of type `T` and not `T[]` and I don't know how to tell the compiler that in this case `T` is an array. What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: One possibly important point - what youve called an array of arrays array is actually known as a jagged array. C# supports both (`double[][]` and `double[,]`). Do you need to support both or are you really only dealing with array of arrays (a jagged array). See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Comment: I need jagged arrays, since I'm playing arround with Accord.Net and their SVM's. And their methods mostly take jagged arrays as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using dynamics:

```
    void Main()
    {
        Print(new double[][]
        {
            new double[] { 1, 2 },
            new double[] { 3, 4 },
            new double[] { 5, 6 },
        });

        // Output: [ 1, 2 ]
        //         [ 3, 4 ]
        //         [ 5, 6 ]
    }

    static void Print(dynamic array)
    {
        if (array.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (array[0].GetType().IsArray)
        {
            foreach (var element in array)
            {
                Print(element);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int size = array.Length;
            string str = "[ ";

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                str += array[i].ToString();

                if (i < size - 1)
                    str += ", ";
            }

            str += " ]";

            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```

If you only want to test smaller part of codes - I suggest using LinqPad where you have AnyType.Dump() method and you mustn't implement anything ;)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about dynamics. Are there any major drawbacks, since any operations regarding dynamics will be resolved at runtime? I can imagine that this could easily be a source of bugs and crashes if used too often?

Comment: There is very good SOF question about that :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478387/how-does-having-a-dynamic-variable-affect-performance

Comment: Not much use for the generic parameter now - but good answer!

Comment: Jamiec - you are right. There is no need for generic now. I will update answer and remove generic

Answer (score 1):

You should provide 2 overloads of your `Print` method - you are free to call the 1D version from the 2D version as you want:

```
static void Print<T>(T[][] array)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Print 2D Array");
}
static void Print<T>(T[] array)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Print 1D Array");
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/LYBUN44476

Comment: While this certainly fixes the problem, it is not as elegant as a single method that does this recursively.  Is there no better way?

Comment: @Neil - thats a matter of opinion, IMO this is *more* elegant as the 2D version just loops through calling the 1D version. Simple, explicit, typesafe. Job done!

Comment: Yeah, but that way I would have to write an additional overload everytime I add a dimension to my array. Is there no way to iterate through any number of dimensions in an array? Thats the reason I tried to build this method with a recursive call to itself.

Comment: @AlexanderMoser I still think your best bet is a simple overload for each extra dimension (how many are you realistically going to have?!) Each one just calls to its predecessor - see updated live example.

Comment: It's a moot point, because in reality you're never likely ever going to need more than one overload for a 2 dimensional array, I agree.  Though I'd have thought there'd be a way of accomplishing this in C# elegantly using one method.

Comment: Thats part of the reason I posted this question, since I couldn't find a "nicer" solution as well. I would like to know if there is a way to make it work the way I tried it. But thanks for your help :)