# Why does this linq with reflection statement beat my compiled expression tree?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

Having been inspired by this [blogpost](https://tyrrrz.me/blog/expression-trees) I set out to refactor the following Linq query using compiled expression trees:

```
var result = dummies.Select(y =>
                   y.GetType().GetProperties()
                   .Where(x => x.GetMethod.IsPublic)
                   .Where(x => fields.Contains(x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(y)))
                   .Where(x => x.Any());
```

The code is intended to extract a set of values of specified properties, returning a dictionary for each element.
In my first encounter with writing my own expression trees I've come up with this solution to generate the property calls:

```
        foreach (string propName in Properties)
        {
            var prop = typeof(DummyType).GetProperty(propName);

            if (prop != null)
            {
                props.Add(prop);
            }
        }

        var accessors = new List<Tuple<string, Func<DummyType, object>>>();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DummyType));
            var call = Expression.Property(instance, prop);
            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<DummyType, object>>(call, instance).Compile();
            accessors.Add(Tuple.Create(prop.Name, expr));
        }
```

For each DummyType element the calls in `accessors` will be iterated This implementation is unable to deal with properties returning value types, though I was able to solve that issue using `MakeGenericType` combined with a `DynamicInvoke` call but because it's documented as "late-bound" I've discarded it to avoid it distorting the performance.

The results are surprising with the Linq query beating my expression trees hands down even though it boxes value types for me and `GetProperties` is called for each element, whereas the linq expression property accessors are generated before collecting the values from the collection of dummytypes.

```
|   Method |         Mean |      Error |     StdDev |  Ratio | RatioSD |
|--------- |-------------:|-----------:|-----------:|-------:|--------:|
|     Linq |     73.09 ns |   0.878 ns |   0.778 ns |   1.00 |    0.00 |
| ExprTree | 16,293.69 ns | 184.834 ns | 172.894 ns | 222.83 |    3.96 |
```

The benchmarks are generated using benchmark.net.

1. Why is the expression tree approach significantly slower?
2. Would it be fair to assume the expression tree solution is faster?
3. Bonus: What effect does using the MakeGenericType solution have on performance in this context?

EDIT:
I've refactored the code somewhat

- It no longer works with generic types but only on `DummyType`
- The linq solution no longer queries for public properties only to deny it the performance benefit
- The expr. tree solution only gets the "accessors"/"function pointers" (?) once when called with the properties to extract and set of DummyType instances whereas the linq query retrieves the properties for every element in the `dummies`  collection
- Only the string property is extracted to avoid having to cater for value type properties on `DummyType`
- A colllection of dictionaries is no longer created but instead a 1 dimensional collection of key-value pairs

```
    public class MyBenchMarks    
    {
        IEnumerable<DummyType> Dummies = DummyType.GenerateDummySet();
        IEnumerable<string> Properties = new string[] { "Prop1" };

        [Benchmark(Description = "Linq", Baseline = true)]
        public Object LinqSolution() => new Mappers().LinqSolution(Properties, Dummies);


        [Benchmark(Description = "ExprTree", Baseline = false)]
        public void ExprTreeSolution() => new Mappers().ExprTreeSolution(Properties, Dummies);
    }

    public class Mappers
    {
        List<Tuple<string, Func<DummyType, object>>> GetAccessors(IEnumerable<string> fields)
        {
            List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(fields.Select(x => typeof(DummyType).GetProperty(x)).Where(x => x != null));
            var accessors = new List<Tuple<string, Func<DummyType, object>>>();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DummyType));
                var call = Expression.Property(instance, prop);
                var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<DummyType, object>>(call, instance).Compile();

                accessors.Add(Tuple.Create(prop.Name, expr));
            }

            return accessors;
        }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ExprTreeSolution(IEnumerable<string> fields, IEnumerable<DummyType> dummies)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
            var accessors = GetAccessors(fields);

            foreach (var dummy in dummies)
            {
                foreach (var accessor in accessors)
                {
                    var propResult = accessor.Item2(dummy);
                    result.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(accessor.Item1, propResult));
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> LinqSolution<T>(IEnumerable<String> fields, IEnumerable<T> dummies)
        {
            var result = dummies.Select(y =>
                  y.GetType().GetProperties()
                  .Where(x => fields.Contains(x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                  .Select(x => KeyValuePair.Create(x.Name, x.GetValue(y))).ToList())
                  .SelectMany(x => x);

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class DummyType
    {
        public bool Prop0 { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }

        public static List<DummyType> GenerateDummySet()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x =>
                 new DummyType
                 {
                     Prop0 = true,
                     Prop1 = "fooBar",
                     Prop2 = x
                 }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The corresponding results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet = v0.12.1, OS = Windows 10.0.19041.630(2004 /?/ 20H1)
Intel Core i5-8600K CPU 3.60GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 6 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.100  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.9 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.47201, CoreFX 4.700.20.47203), X64 RyuJIT[AttachedDebugger]
DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.9 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.47201, CoreFX 4.700.20.47203), X64 RyuJIT

|   Method |         Mean |      Error |     StdDev |    Ratio | RatioSD |
|--------- |-------------:|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|--------:|
| Linq     | 66.14 ns     | 0.162 ns   | 0.143 ns   | 1.00     | 0.00    |
| ExprTree | 70,366.57 ns | 500.248 ns | 443.457 ns | 1,063.84 | 7.51    |
```

this code can be run from a console application using

```
BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

Comment: You have shown code in version A, and version B, that's great. However, often, no one will be able to answer you a performance-specific question, unless you provide a fully runnable code. That's because sometimes the problem lies elsewhere. Like the not shown `Dummy` class - version A filters props by IsPublic, version B does not. It might be a critical difference, but who will guess when Dummy class is unknown? Also, the selection of input data may sometimes impact the measurement. We don't see it. And so on.

Comment: The best chances to get it diagnosed is to prepare a fully-self-contained, runnable example, that we'll be able to compile on out machines, and see both results.. if it gets large, maybe post it on github?

Comment: As for guessing, version B doesn't do: `.Where(x => fields.Contains(x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that LinqSolution is returning a deferred LINQ `IEnumerable<>`. It's not actually doing the work (reflection). Try changing `return result` to `return result.ToList()`. That'll at least help ensure you're comparing apples to apples.

[image]

Beyond that, recognize that the act of compiling an expression is quite expensive. You probably won't see a big performance gain unless you reuse the compiled function many more times. To see this in action, try generating 10000 items in GenerateDummySet instead of just 100.

[image]

To take advantage of this in real-world code, try memoizing the compiled function (using a static `Lazy<>` initialization, for example).

Comment: Thanks for spotting the deferred execution slip! The results are now more in line with expectations.

Comment: No worries. You may also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478557/120955).

Answer (score 0):

Another guess, adding to my comments: I just noticed that both version A and version B seems to return the final values as read from the dummies' properties.

If you have measured the time of version A and version B exactly as they are shown here, then do note that you're measuring not only the time of accessing the data via one or the other way, but you are also measuring the time for setting up all things.

For example, in version A, you are ***probably*** saving some time using `y.GetType().GetProperties()` which gets all props in one go, while in version B you're doing something ***probably*** very wasteful by going over some "properties" list and separately looking up each property by name: `var prop = typeof(DummyType).GetProperty(propName);`

Furthermore, if you measured it as shown, then version B includes generating dynamic assembly (or assembles) at runtime at the point where you `.Compile();` the expression. That might have costed a lot of time, that could add a lot to the statistics.

So... I think you have to seriously revise your question. It's missing a lot of important information, and all we can do is guessing.