# Define a class member that can be one of either two classes

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I am working with a tree that contains two different types of nodes, inner and outer ones. I would like to have members 'leftChild' and 'rightChild' in the inner node class that can point to either an inner or an outer node. Is there any way to do this?

I tried creating a base class and inherite the two types of node from that, which works but then I can't access any of the individual members of the child when I navigate to it from the tree.

```csharp
public abstract class Node {
    public Node parent;
}
public class InnerNode : Node {
    private Node leftChild, rightChild;
    private int someInnerNodeMember;
}
public class OuterNode : Node {
    private float someOuterNodeMember;
}
```

My only solution at the moment is to have every child member twice for each class and set the one that is not used to null, which makes things a lot more complicated.

```csharp
public class InnerNode : Node {
    private InnerNode leftChildAsInner, rightChildAsInner;
    private OuterNode leftChildAsOuter, rightChildAsOuter;
    private int someInnerNodeMember;
}
public class OuterNode : Node {
    private float someOuterNodeMember;
}
```

I'm rather new to C# and come from C, so I might not be familiar with some very basic mechanics, but if so I did not manage to find anything helpful.

Comment: @PoulBak: How would that help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you need here some kind of [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) i.e. if you have two methods for each type, dynamically decide which method to call.

TL;DR Visitor Pattern, dynamic keyword or switch case. In any case you would need separate block of code of function for each subtype(and in this block or function you will have concrete subtype and therefore access to all its members).

In practice I would say switch case way is used the most, dynamic I think almost never.

#### Visitor

One of the solutions would be here to use [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). You would need a separate method for each subtype you use and then it could be used like this.

```cs
public abstract class Node
{
    public Node parent;
    public abstract void Accept(Visitor visitor);
}
public class InnerNode : Node
{
    internal Node leftChild, rightChild;
    internal int someInnerNodeMember;

    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
public class OuterNode : Node
{
    internal float someOuterNodeMember;


    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Visitor
{
    public void Visit(InnerNode inner)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inner node {inner.someInnerNodeMember}" );
    }

    public void Visit(OuterNode outer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Outer node {outer.someOuterNodeMember}");

    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var visitor = new Visitor();
        var inner = new InnerNode
        {
            leftChild = new InnerNode { someInnerNodeMember = 1 },
            rightChild = new OuterNode { someOuterNodeMember = 12 }
        };

        inner.leftChild.Accept(visitor);
        inner.rightChild.Accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

Visitor is basically the place where you apply your logic, so if it the InnerNode is the place where you want to be able to distinguish between Inner and Outer node type, then it would be visitor as well, and you could move visitor methods to the inner node and  rewrite the program like this

```cs
public abstract class Node
{
    public Node parent;
    public abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
}
public class InnerNode : Node, IVisitor
{
    internal Node leftChild, rightChild;
    internal int someInnerNodeMember;

    public void PrintChildrenDetails()
    {
        leftChild?.Accept(this);
        rightChild?.Accept(this);
    }

    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }

    public void Visit(InnerNode inner)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inner node {inner.someInnerNodeMember}");
    }

    public void Visit(OuterNode outer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Outer node {outer.someOuterNodeMember}");

    }
}
public class OuterNode : Node
{
    internal float someOuterNodeMember;


    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(InnerNode inner);
    void Visit(OuterNode inner);

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inner = new InnerNode
        {
            leftChild = new InnerNode { someInnerNodeMember = 1 },
            rightChild = new OuterNode { someOuterNodeMember = 12 }
        };

        inner.PrintChildrenDetails();
    }
}
```

#### dynamic

Same can be acheived using dynamic keyword, it is rather not recommended though(it has performance issues [e.g. see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478387/how-does-having-a-dynamic-variable-affect-performance))

```cs
public abstract class Node
{
    public Node parent;
}
public class InnerNode : Node
{
    internal Node leftChild, rightChild;
    internal int someInnerNodeMember;

    public void PrintChildrenDetails()
    {
        Process((dynamic)leftChild);
        Process((dynamic)rightChild);
    }

    public void Process(InnerNode inner)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inner node {inner.someInnerNodeMember}");
    }

    public void Process(OuterNode outer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Outer node {outer.someOuterNodeMember}");

    }
}
public class OuterNode : Node
{
    internal float someOuterNodeMember;
}



public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inner = new InnerNode
        {
            leftChild = new InnerNode { someInnerNodeMember = 1 },
            rightChild = new OuterNode { someOuterNodeMember = 12 }
        };

        inner.PrintChildrenDetails();
    }
}
```

#### Switch expression

Simply have switch expression and handle each type case.

```cs
public abstract class Node
{
    public Node parent;
}
public class InnerNode : Node
{
    internal Node leftChild, rightChild;
    internal int someInnerNodeMember;

    public void PrintChildrenDetails()
    {
        Process(leftChild);
        Process(rightChild);
    }

    public void Process(Node node)
    {
        switch (node)
        {
            case InnerNode inner:
                Console.WriteLine($"Inner node {inner.someInnerNodeMember}");
                break;
            case OuterNode outer:
                Console.WriteLine($"Outer node {outer.someOuterNodeMember}");
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class OuterNode : Node
{
    internal float someOuterNodeMember;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inner = new InnerNode
        {
            leftChild = new InnerNode { someInnerNodeMember = 1 },
            rightChild = new OuterNode { someOuterNodeMember = 12 }
        };

        inner.PrintChildrenDetails();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the base class:

```cs
public class InnerNode : Node {
    private Node leftChild, rightChild;
    private int someInnerNodeMember;
}
```

Of course, that means that you have to check on access whether it's an inner or an outer node, but that's not much different from checking whether one of the members is null.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is trying not to do.

Comment: I tried this, but then when I try to iterate through the tree and do for example `currentInnerNode.leftChild.leftChild`, I get the error `'Node' does not contain a definition for 'leftChild'`.

Comment: @Deimos_9921 That's true, but that's normally not how you iterate over a tree. You should visit one level at a time. If you need to write `.leftChild.leftChild` you are accessing the child of a child, which will make things complicated (look at the accepted solution, it also iterates one step at a time)