# Create JObject with propertyname.subname

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to create a JObject on the fly for unit testing but it does not seem to like `name.subname` as a property

The json that I am trying to create JObject for is

```
   { "UserDetails": {
          "FirstName": "Test1",
          "Surname": "Test2",
          "UserID": "123456789",
          "Children1.Active1": false,
          "Children1.Active2": false
    }
}
```

The C# code I have is

```
dynamic jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.UserDetails = new JObject();
jsonObject.UserDetails.UserID = "123456789";
jsonObject.UserDetails.FirstName = "Test1";
jsonObject.UserDetails.Surname= "Test2";
```

However i am not sure how to add `Children1.Active` to the JObject `jsonObject. UserDetails` it does not work with `jsonObject.UserDetails.Children.Active1 = false`.

I have validated the json and it passes validation for being valid json.

How can I add `Children1.Active` to JObject?

I have tried `jsonObject.UserDetails.Children1 = new JObject();`
But this creates a new sub object which is not what I need.

Comment: Sounds like `Children1` needs to be an array or object itself. That's not a good JSON schema. As for the question itself, *instead* of trying to access `JObject` as a dynamic object, use its own properties and set properties and keys. You don't need `dynamic` in *this* code anyway - store the `UserDetails` object in a separate variable and you won't need to access it through `jsonObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Children1.Active2"` isn't a nested object, it's a property with a period in the name string.  And since you're doing everything via `dynamic`, this becomes a nuisance, as c# identifiers can't include such a character even though JSON property names can.

In such cases, instead of using `dynamic`, it's easier to do things with a typed [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and its compile-time-bound methods, specifically its [string indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) method:

```
var jsonObject = new JObject();
var userDetails = new JObject();
jsonObject["UserDetails"] = userDetails;
userDetails["UserID"] = "123456789";
userDetails["FirstName"] = "Test1";
userDetails["Surname"] = "Test2";           
userDetails["Children1.Active1"] = false;
userDetails["Children1.Active2"] = false;
```

This should also be more performant as `dynamic` can have some [run-time performance penalties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784317/3744182).

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dV8uFm).